# If for same column in table 1 value exists in table 2 then add the two values.Else take the previous value from table 2 and then add

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables Table 1 and Table  like :

Table 1

```
ID     Product_Id         Date                        Volume
1        260       2015-07-21 09:50:37.000             40000
1        270       2015-07-23 09:50:37.000             60000
```

Table 2

```
ID          Product_Id          Date                       Volume
2            260              2015-07-21 09:50:37.000      10000
2            270              2015-07-22 09:50:37.000      20000
```

I want to check if Product_Id for a date in table 1 is present in table 2 or not and if it is present then I want to add the two volumes. If not present then I will take the previous value from table 2 and then add.

How to achieve this? I am not getting a single idea to do this.

Comment: Please provide sample result data that you expect in above case

Comment: Need the result data that you want in that table. Providing only the column name will not suffice

Comment: Yes.Updated my comment.

Comment: Final table should look like :                                                                      Product_Id          date                Volume
260      2015-07-21      50000
270             2015-07-22              60000

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e832fd/2)

**Schema Details**

```
create table t1
(
  id integer,
  product_id integer,
  date datetime,
  volume integer
);

create table t2
(
  id integer,
  product_id integer,
  date datetime,
  volume integer
);

insert into t1 values(1,260, '2015-07-21 09:50:37.000', 40000);
insert into t1 values(2,270, '2015-07-23 09:50:37.000', 60000);

insert into t2 values(2,260, '2015-07-21 09:50:37.000', 10000);
insert into t2 values(2,270, '2015-07-22 09:50:37.000', 20000);
```

**Select Query**

```
select product_id, date, 
volume+coalesce((select volume from t2 where t1.product_id=t2.product_id and t1.date=t2.date),0)
from t1
```

**Output**

```
| product_id |                   date |       |
|------------|------------------------|-------|
|        260 | July, 21 2015 09:50:37 | 50000 |
|        270 | July, 23 2015 09:50:37 | 60000 |
```

Comment: I first want to check whether for the date in table t2 I have a volume in table t1 or not. if there is a volume then for that date it will add those and if not then it will take the previous value of volume from table t1 and then add. So how should I check this condition?

Comment: If the above query does not satisfy your requirement, add more data to your question and expected output from it. I will refine the query.